# как в гитхаб очистить историю без коммита

Tags: github

есть приложение github для виндоус в котором вывелись файлы кеша и тп ненужные которые не хочется коммитить в общий репозиторий но они копятся и мешают просмотру, как их очистить со списка без push

Comment: Не совсем понял, что именно вам нужно. На сколько я понял, в лучшем случае `.gitignore`, в худшем -- интерактивный `rebase`.

Comment: "Очищать" нужно превентивно - заранее добавляя ненужные папки и файлы в файл `.gitignore`. А теперь без push не очистить. При любом раскладе будет как минимум один пуш) Вообще не понятно, с чем связано такое требование.

Comment: ну если более подробно написать, есть сайт на опенкарт и в гитхаб программе некоторые файлы вроде cache.store45345435 примерно или с такого типа названиями не удаляются и после того как добавить их в  .gitignore но речь идет об удаленных файлах то есть был файл такой то в кеше а потом он был удален системой (в локальном веб сервере) но в репозитории он пишется и не удаляется